# invalid type argument of unary in c

Tags: arrays, c, loops, pointers

I'm writing a function:

`int findSumInArray(int *arr, int size, int *sum, int **num1, int **num2)`

sum : the user choose a number(sum) and we check if there is num1+num2==sum (two numbers in the same array).
if we got two numbers like this ,then we want to know the i and j for these numbers also the value of arr[i] and arr[j]
I dont know what is wrong in my function !?
I'm getting : invalid type argument of unary .

```
int findSumInArray(int *arr, int size, int *sum, int **num1, int **num2)
{
int i=0,j=0;
  if(scanf("%d", sum)!=1)
  return -1;
     for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
                {
                if(*(arr+i)+*(arr+j)==*sum)
                    {
                    **num1=*(arr+i);
                    **num2=*(arr+j);
                    ***num1=i;
                    ***num1=j;
                    return 1;
                    }
                }
        }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Is it "invalid type argument of unary in c"?

Comment: yes ..its in the title of my question

Comment: Given that `num1` is declared `int **num1`, what do you think `***num1` is? What are you trying to do with `***num1=i;`.

Comment: You want to return the two found number in the array as well as their indices. So you need to have 4 pointers as argument. But returning both the index and the value is not needed because the index is enough: the caller obviously has the array and can fetch de values from the array.

Comment: I decelared the two arguments in the main                                                                    int* num1,num2;                                                                                                  int arr[size];                                                                                                          I fixed the function as u said and updated jus the index into num1 and num2,                   now....I have to print them     , but I don't know exactly how printf("arr[%d]= %d +arr[%d] =%d ==sum\n",num1,*(arr+*num1),num2,*(arr+*num2));  ?? is that correct?